# How to distinguish a request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating an API and I would like to distinguish GET, DELETE, MODIFY, POST requests.

Is it possible to distinguish that from a controller?

For example:

Distinguish: (GET REQUEST)

```
GET http://myapi.com/POST/1234
```

From DELETE REQUEST

```
DELETE http://myapi.com/POST/1234
```

Can I do that from post controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a controller action method, do:

```
request.method
```

It's going to say which HTTP method was used.

You can also use:

```
request.get?
request.post?
request.delete?
```

And so on.

For full documentation on the class, [check here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you map your routes RESTfully (see [this tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)), the DELETE verb on that resource will map to a different controller action than the GET request.

GET maps to `show` and DELETE maps to `destroy`.